# Provide Auto Save functionality in my jsp using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, autosave

I have a jsp, which is using lot of  tag. Each table has a section for user input fields. I want to provide Auto Save functionality for the whole jsp page, only if something has changed in the whole page.
I can use Javascript or Jquery for the same. I need suggestions as to how should I implement the same maybe after 40 sec of inactivity.
I cannot read each text box as there are many of them.
I need a generic way for knowing if any text box in the whole page has been changed, I need to save after 40 sec of inactivity.

```
<s:textfield cssClass="label" key="loeEDBCDsgnHrs"                                                                                          label="" cssStyle="width:50;"                                                                                                                   maxlength="5" />
```

Comment: divide section of your page make ajax request of update in each section

Comment: instead of having onChange functionality on each of the field you can wrap the fields into a single form tag, since event bubbling happens if any of the field changes if you have written an onChange on the form level you will be able to catch it.

Comment: Any code suggestions on ajax request please. I am new to this coding world. Or any link would also be helpful